# Overriding default delete action in eclipse navigator view

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am working on an RCP application that has eclipse navigator viewer with ID org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer. I want to override delete action (DeleteResourceAction) in order to do something before my resources are deleted from workspace/file system. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.deleteParticipants](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ltk_core_refactoring_deleteParticipants.html) extension point to add a participant that is called whenever resources are deleted.

Your code extends the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.DeleteParticipant` class.

Some more details in [this article](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-LTK/ltk.html)

The delete participant is called before the delete is performed to check that the delete can be performed. It then provides a set of Change objects that are called during the actual delete. There are also rename, copy and move participants.

For building you can add builders to a project description to get code run during the build.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping to more general way of doing this, for example, if I want to override build action, I cannot use this. Also, will this work if I want to have the code before actual deletion? eg. I want to save resources before removing them from workspace (not file system).

Comment: Added more details of the various participants and builders.

Comment: This kinda did the trick, though in order to get the result of the delete content flag (from ws or file system), I had to change some of their source code.
In any case, thanks for your help greg :).